# ActiveMQ/JMS network messaging

Tags: rabbitmq, jms, activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

Sorry if this is answered in the documentation, but I need some more insight.   We currently use RabbitMQ, and need a distributed system.   I would like to build a distributed system with  3 or more distributed brokers, named NEWYORK, NEVADA and TEXAS.   Looking to see if it is workable to send Q messages with routing keys like, NEWYORK.terminal.abc from NEVADA with the ability to send a reply back with a replyTo type option.    Also, things like:  NEVADA.jobQueue.fastpace from TEXAS. or  TEXAS.queues.ect.

Then ability to send TOPIC type messages from NEWYORK.weather and other sites subscribe to NEWYORK.weather.   ect.. ect..

Is this something that ActiveMQ/Artemis can do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "routing keys"? To my knowledge this is not something which is part of JMS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this sort of data transmission is done all the time with ActiveMQ.

Tip: Topics become confusing and complicated to configure once you go to a multi-broker architecture. Look into using Virtual Topics or Composite Destinations to get your data subscriptions lined up how you want, while maintaining pub-sub pattern.

Virtual Topic summary:

1. Producers end to a topic
2. Consumers read from specially named queue(s)
3. Ability to have multiple subscribers, and separate local traffic with over-the-wan traffic into separate queues
4. Support for consumer-provided server-side filtering using JMS standard selectors

ref: https://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations